# Trace of permutation matrix

Tags: matrices, permutation-matrices

If we have the symmetric group $S_k$ I know we can represent this as a permutation matrix and that this representation is a group homomorphism defined by say $f$. Where $f$ sends the symmetric group to an $n \times n$ matrix.

I was wondering how to show that the trace of $f$ was equal to the number of $x={1,... k}$ such that $h(x)=x$, where $h$ is our permutation?

So I can see for example that $(1,4,2,5,3)$ there are no elements on the diagonal so the trace is zero as no elements sends itself to itself. However I was wondering if there was a better way to show this more generally?

Comment: This is almost trivial. The trace of the matrix is the sum of the diagonal elements. These are $0$ or $1$, and they are $1$ only when the index $i$ is mapped to itself...

Comment: I understand it is trivial but I was wondering if there were a more formal way of expressing it rather than just one sentence @Crostul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\sigma \in S_n$, the corresponding permutation matrix is
$$
P_\sigma = \begin{pmatrix} e_{\sigma(1)}\\ \vdots\\  e_{\sigma(n)}  \end{pmatrix}
$$ where the $e_k$'s are standard basis row vectors: $e_k (j) = \delta_{k,j} = \begin{cases} 1 \ k = j \\ 0 \ k \neq j \end{cases}$. So
$$
\text{tr}(P_\sigma) = \sum_{i = 1}^nP_\sigma(i, i) = \sum_{i = 1}^n e_{\sigma(i)}(i) = \sum_{i = 1}^n 
\delta(\sigma(i), i) = \sum_{i = 1 : \sigma(i) \neq i}^n 0 + \sum_{i = 1 : \sigma(i) = i}^n 1
$$ which is just $\#\{1 \leq i \in \mathbb N \leq n : \sigma(i) = i\}$.